# Parameters Affecting Demagnetisation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

What parameters will affect how a ferromagnetic material is demagnetised? Assuming that only changing fields will induce demagnetisation (although I suppose I could well be wrong on that one), what constraints are there on frequency, and how would the magnetic field be able to affect it? Would the size and/or shape of the material help to determine these parameters, or would it be (mostly) magnet design independent.

In school we may use mains electricity to demagnetise a magnet, so that, and the formula for the field due to (and inductance of) a solenoid gives me a ballpark idea of what is possible for a given voltage, and ergo magnetic field, but no concept whatsoever of how this might vary.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you searched for material on DEGAUSSING or DEMAGNETIZATION ENERGY on the web?

Comment: The stuff I've found thus far which mentions 'demagnetising energy' has all been papers behind a paywall, and 'degaussing' as a process tends to pull up references to the application of the technique, rather than the theory behind it, or anything on the parameters affecting it.

Comment: Keep looking, there is useful stuff to be found. physics textbooks also deal with this. try websites for companies that sell magnetic materials too.

Comment: Mains frequency is fine, higher frequencies do not penetrate very far in metals. Move the degaussing coil away before switching it off.

Comment: So should I be considering the magnetic skin-depth of the metal, then, when looking at how far the field propagates. And even given that, in my research I still haven't found factors determining how much, for a given field and/or frequency, it demagnetises, although I can qualitatively understand that the penetration distance would be related to it (if there's - approximately - no field, I would expect no change, that's logical).